# If the function $f^2$ is differentiable, then is the function $f$ differentiable as well?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

True or False

"If the function $f^2$ on reals is differentiable, then so is the function $f$ on reals"

It would be easy to prove the other way around.

Do I need to use the limit definition, I couldn't think of a counter example off hand...

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What about a function which is $1$ on the rationals and $-1$ on the irrationals?

Comment: Or, simpler: a function that's 1 on the nonnegatives and -1 on the negatives.

Comment: What about $f^2 = |x|^2 = x^2$ and $f = |x|$?

Comment: Thank you, I think my understanding of this was flawed, I am going back to study. I appreciate it.

Comment: The answer doesn't change, but everyone here seems to be assuming that $f^2=f\cdot  f$, but usually in Math it refers to $f\circ f$. If this is what is meant, you'll just need a different counterexample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple enough counter-example suffices.

Take $f^2 = |x|^2 = x^2$ which is everywhere differentiable and $f = |x|$ which fails to be differentiable at $0$, so the claim is false.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a (hopefully) useful addition to the accepted answer, I would note that if we, instead, add the conditions that $f(x)^2 \neq 0$ and $f$ is continuous, then it *is* true that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. To prove this, we will need to make use of the following lemma:

> For the function $f=g \cdot h$, if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=M \neq 0$, then $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)=\frac{L}{M} \quad (\dagger_1)$ .

Note: the "$f$ is continuous" assumption is a must. Without this assumption, the given continuity of $f^2$ (from its differentiability) is insufficient to conclude that $f$ is continuous...consider the function:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}x \quad  &\text{ if $x \in \mathbb Q$} \\-x \quad &\text{if $x \notin \mathbb Q$} \end{cases}$

---

**PROOF**

Consider an arbitrary $x$ such that $f^2(x)\neq 0$. This means that $f(x) \neq 0$. Now, by assumption, we have that $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f^2(x+h)-f^2(x)}{h}=D$. Consider the equivalent expression:

$$\frac{f^2(x+h)-f^2(x)+f(x+h)f(x)-f(x+h)f(x)}{h}$$

This expression can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{f(x+h)\cdot \big( f(x+h)-f(x)\big)-f(x)\cdot\big(f(x)-f(x+h)\big)}{h}$$, which can be further simplified to:

$$\frac{f(x+h)\cdot \big(f(x+h)-f(x)\big)}{h}+\frac{f(x)\cdot\big(f(x+h)-f(x)\big)}{h}=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\cdot \big(f(x+h)+f(x)\big)$$

As such, we have that:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\cdot \big(f(x+h)+f(x)\big)=D$$

We would like to invoke our lemma $(\dagger_1)$, where we treat $\phi$ as $\phi(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and $\psi$ as $\psi(h)=f(x+h)+f(x)$. Because $f$ is assumed to be continuous, we know that $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h)+f(x)=2f(x)\neq 0$.

We can now apply $(\dagger_1)$, which gives us that $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{D}{2f(x)}$